# Enable or disable registered receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-package-managers

I have problems providing correct attributes to "setComponentEnabledSetting()" - I get IllegalAttributeException saying that .class can't be find, or doesn't exist.

Receivers are declared in application manifest, and receiver handlers are stored in a separate package (com.app.receivers). In manifest file their name attribute is ".receivers.OnBoot". Till now I didn't have any problems with this setup - receivers are working, etc., but now I am trying to add a feature for user to enable/disable receivers.

```
ComponentName rec = new ComponentName("com.app.receivers", "OnBoot.class");
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(rec, ....);
```

I have tried many different alternatives to get valid ComponentName, but all failed.
How can I properly reference this receiver so that setComponentEnabledSetting() will find it?

Comment: have you tried it as `ComponentName rec = new ComponentName("com.app.receivers", "com.app.receivers.OnBoot");...` ?

Comment: oh well.. I guess sometimes you have to post a question just before you find where problem is :) yes, ofcourse, ....I don't know where this .class came from and wasn't paying attention to it. Sure, it is working :) Please post as an answer so that I can accept your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `BroadcastReceiver` class name with full package name as second parameter to `ComponentName` instead of `OnBoot.class` try it as:

```
ComponentName rec = new ComponentName("com.app.receivers",
                                            "com.app.receivers.OnBoot");
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(rec, ....);
```